# How to convert all the factor variable into integers in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I tried this line of code. I think it worked earlier now its giving up.

```
lapply(is.factor(df),levels(df)=(1:length(levels(df))))
```

I want to convert all the factor variables into integers values like 1,2,3 etc.

Comment: `indx <- sapply(df, is.factor) ; df[indx] <- lapply(df[indx], as.integer)`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg is my attempt terribly wrong because if im not wrong it worked once.

Comment: `lapply` doesn't work like that. You will need to specify an anonymous functions in order for your solution to work. Also you will need to loop over the columns in `df` instead of just a logical vector of length one. For example, `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) levels(x) = (1:length(levels(x))) else x)`, but you probably don't need this complication. You can also use `nlevels` instead of `length(levels())` btw.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Thanks very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.  You should pass the data frame as the first argument in `lapply` and then run `is.factor` as part of the function that makes up the second argument of `lapply`

```
DFrame <- data.frame(x = letters[1:3],
                     y = letters[4:6],
                     z = LETTERS[9:11])

DFrame <- lapply(DFrame, 
                 function(t)
                   if (is.factor(t)) as.numeric(t) else t)
DFrame <- as.data.frame(DFrame)
DFrame

vapply(DFrame, class, character(1))
```

Comment: I knew this one but was trying for a better method which i think is above one. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the new [purrr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/index.html), this becomes a nice one-liner:

```r
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(x = letters[1:3],
                 y = letters[4:6],
                 z = LETTERS[9:11])

df %>% map_if(is.factor, as.numeric) %>% str()
#> 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
#> $ x: num  1 2 3
#> $ y: num  1 2 3
#> $ z: num  1 2 3
```